# I could not connect to ms access database from jsp with below code though added as odbc system dsn

Tags: jsp, ms-access

I could not connect to ms access database from jsp with below code though added as odbc system dsn. However I could insert into database using java servlet code. JSP IS DONE FROM NETBEANS.

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <table border=1>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td></tr>
    <%
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student"," ", " ");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data");
    while(rs.next()){
        %>
    <tr><td><%=rs.getString("name")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("address")%></td></tr>
    <%
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    %>
    </table>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Anyone who writes `catch(Exception e){}` should be slapped. And who writes it after a try block with JDBC/SQL commands should be flogged with cat o' nine tails.